Issue with woocommerce parent child category url
In WooCommerce, child categories have the following URL structure:
site.com/product-category/parent-category/child-category.
However, if I modify the "parent-category" part of the URL in the browser, like this:
site.com/product-category/parenwqewqt-qwecategory/child-category, the page still returns a 200 status code instead of a 404, even though the URL is incorrect.
This seems to be a common WooCommerce issue that could lead to SEO problems, as invalid URLs are not properly flagged as 404 errors.
I tried to create a hook to fix this, but it didn't work. Here's the code I used:
I create this but nothing changes:
add_action('template_redirect', 'custom_woocommerce_category_404');
function custom_woocommerce_category_404() {
    if (is_product_category()) {
        $category = get_queried_object();
        if (!$category || !term_exists($category->slug, 'product_cat')) {
            global $wp_query;
            $wp_query->set_404();
            status_header(404);
            nocache_headers();
            include(get_query_template('404'));
            exit;
        }
    }
}

How can I modify this or create a proper hook to return a 404 error when the URL structure is incorrect?

$category = get_queried_object(); - have you verified what that actually contains? My guess would be that this only contains the term object corresponding to your child-category from the URL, and the parent-category part got ignored to begin with. I'm guessing you will likely have to look at the actually requested URL, and take that apart yourself.
